# Swagger UI using swasbuckle is getting me CORS Origin issue on login redirect from Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I'm facing a new issue with swashbuckle and login redirection after make a request and my token has been expired. [image: description]
I really don't know if is a common issue or if this thins can't be done, that's  why I make the question.
My request to my api enponit redirects fine but, when I click the Execute button on swagger UI, the request to https://localhost:port/api/v1/Contacts, the response is 302 and then try to redirect me to my login provider with this issue and I cannot redirect to login again.[image: image 2]

What I'm missing here????

this is my authentication config:

```
 //Add  Auth options
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = ClientId;
            options.Authority = $"{Instance}/{TenantId}";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = SignedOutRedirectUri;
            // Add needed scopes
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("roles");

            options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };

        })
        .AddCookie()
       .AddAzureAdBearer(options => configuration.Bind("bearer", options));
```

Comment: Cookie auth is triggering and trying to redirect to login page which is not what you want here. You'll want to make the API routes use the AzureAdBearer authentication scheme.

Comment: @juunas How can I do this?